# What questions raised by ancient Greek philosophy were answered by Christianity?

Tags: church-history, philosophy

I have heard several Christian philosophers (Robert Koons, Dallas Willard, for example) say that Christianity emphatically answered a lot of questions posed by ancient Greek philosophy. For example, there is the case of the Logos, which according to Greek philosophy was that hypothetical principle which if honored would allow you to fulfill your true purpose. Christianity says that the Logos exists but is not a principle, but a person.

What other questions of the ancient Greeks were answered by Christianity?

Comment: I don't know that your Logos example is a good one, in what form is the answer to purpose better as a person than a principle?

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you a list of these questions for I don't know them but I think it is very important to know that Greeks, in their search for truth, somehow realized there should be a God to worship (distinct from the gods they had created in their mythology) so at the time when the apostles came, they had been worshipping a so-called 'Agnostos Theos' (The Unknown/Anonymous God). And apparently, at least, the Christian truth that was preached by Paul was exactly what they had been waiting for!

Answer (score 0):

1. The eternity of the world is a major tenant of almost all the ancient Greek philosophers, including Plato and Aristotle. However, it is an article of the Faith (*de fide*) that **the world had a beginning in time**:

   > John 17:5: “And now glorify thou me, O Father, with thyself, with the glory which I had before the world was with thee.”
   > Eph. 1:4: “He chose us in Him (Christ) even before the foundation of the world.”
   > Ps. 101:26: “In the beginning, O Lord, thou foundest the earth.”
   > Cf. Gn. 1:1; Pro. 8:22 et seq.; Ps. 89:2; John 17:24.

   We also know that philosophical arguments cannot prove or disprove the eternity of the world (cf. St. Thomas Aquinas's [*S. th.* I 46, 1](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP/FP046.html#FPQ46A1THEP1) and [*De aeternitate mundi*](https://isidore.co/aquinas/DeEternitateMundi.htm)), thus the revelation of this truth by God was morally necessary.
2. ***Creatio ex nihilo*** ("creation out of nothing") is another concept that Greek philosophers, including Aristotle, never arrived at. *Creatio ex nihilo* is proved in:

   > Gn. 1:1: “In the beginning God created Heaven and earth.”